# Is there a way to add code to make the dev of a plugin have all of the commands by default?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have made a few MC plugins, and would like to know if this is possible.
If so, would you mind helping me a bit? If I need to provide more info, please don't hesitate to ask <3

Comment: How do you deal with the permissions for each command? If I understand you correctly, you want to have permission to use all the commands by default on your plugins. Is this correct?

Comment: You shouldn't distribute a plugin with a back door such as this... It will never get approved on Bukkit Dev

Answer (score 1):

You could always add a manual check to your commmand code when checking the permission, like so:

```
private static String DEVELOPER = "user3262369";

public void doMyCommand(Player player)
{
    if(player.hasPermission("mymod.permission.name") ||
       player.getName().equals(DEVELOPER))
    {
        //Do whatever your command does here
    }
}
```

For more information, see the [Permissions section of the Bukkit Plugin tutorial](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#Permissions) and the Bukkit [`org.bukkit.entity.Player` API](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html).